# Using Clob with Spring NamedParameterJdbc Template

Tags: xml, string, spring, clob

I need to store large XML data to CLOB and convert back CLOB to String

But the problem is we are using (Spring NamedParameterJdbc template)

```
SqlParameterSource paramSource = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(
            positionResponsesDO);
this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql, paramSource);
```

Where PositionResponsesDO has get and set property

```
private Clob xmlData;
```

Now I need to convert String data (large) to Clob and Clob to String.
Please suggest to me the best way.

I can't use File operations as it's WebApp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`LobHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/LobHandler.html) and [`LobCreator`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/LobCreator.html) to take Clobs and Blobs and turn them into something else.

The [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-lob) discusses them here.

To convert a clob or blob column to something , you can use a `query()` method on `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` that takes a `RowMapper`.

```
LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, paramSource,
    new RowMapper<Void>() {
        public Void mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
            String clobText = lobHandler.getClobAsString(rs, "clobColumnName");                                                
            byte[] blobBytes = lobHandler.getBlobAsBytes(rs, "blobColumnName");                                                
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: It works if we are retriving results using RowMapper.
But how to use it with BeanPropertySqlParameterSource. Because this Spring utility maps bean properties with db column. So if i mark bean property with String (respective column in db is Clob), will that works?